# I have created a module using gii in yii2 , declared that in yii console.php in config , still can't access by index.php/moduleid

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-components

```
namespace app\modules\forum;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\forum\controllers';

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));
    // custom initialization code goes here
}
}
```

this is my module class

and

```
'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',



    'forum' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\forum\Module',
    ],

    'test' => [
        'class' => 'app\test\Module',
    ],
],
```

this is console.php in config , I am using basic of yii2

Comment: If you are using `UrlManager` please update your question with `urlManager` configs.

Comment: I am not using url manager @AliMasudianPour

Comment: I assume you are calling index.php/moduleid/controller/action, right?

Comment: Its solved now ! thanks .. the download copy has some issues I guess